# Calculate correlation of a million of pairs in a efficient way

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, correlation, coding-efficiency

How i can compute in a reaseonable amount of time, the correlation of a two time series of two product prices?
I have a set of products length of 8485. The possible combination is around 36 millions of pairs.
Each product is a pandas series with a TimeStamp index (in days) with the prices values. The data time is about 1 year.

For example, the data of some product is like:

```
            price
2020-01-01  200  
2020-01-02  250
...         ...
2021-02-01  600
```

I save the data in tuples with the id of product:

```
products = tuple((id_products, series_products)) = ((111, series_product_111), (222, series_product_222), ...)
len(products) = 8485
```

I need de maximum cross-correlation of the prices of each products (Im using pandas shift function for crossing data, and pandas corr function for calculate correlation) in a nested loop. For that, I created a list with the all posible combinations (35M) of indexes called list_products.

```
list_products= [(i,j) for i in range(len(products)) for j in range(len(products)) if i<j]
```

On the other hand, the time series have different sizes, so to calculate the correlation at the same length of time, I created a function called -subset_datatime-

```
correlation = list()
for i,j in list_products:
    series_1, series_2 = subset_datatime(products[i][1], products[j][1])
    
    correlation.append([ series1.corr(series2.shift(t)) for t in range(-10,10)], 
                         products[i][0],
                         products[j][0]))
```

Unfortunately this can take up to 3 days on my computer. Is there a more efficient way to achieve it?

Comment: Have you thought of merging the DataFrames so as to have comumn per product? You could also transform the whole thing into a numpy 2D array.

Comment: I will probe with merging DataFrames